# Data tree with dynamic data and topCalc

Tags: javascript, tabulator

In tabulator, I'm trying to get a few things to play nicely together. I have come close to a working solution, but new problems keep popping up. Some help would definitely be appreciated!

I have some data, and as I am trying to display a datatree, I have defined some children for it.

What I am trying to achieve is to display some aggregated data in the parent-row. The data is contained in the children. To be more specific in my example: I want the parent row to display total-views, whereas the children display the views for one particular date.

Not much of a problem. The trouble begins when I try to add a topCalc and filters to the equation of this particular challenge.

The code would look something like this:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/muffinimal/oe3fyp4d/20/).

```js
let tabledata = [
    {id:1, isParent: true, title:"Making sense", date:"01/02/2016", _children:[
       {date:"01/02/2016", title:"Making sense 1", views: 204},
       {date:"07/02/2017", title:"Making sense 2", views: 21},
    ]},
    {id:1, isParent: true, title:"Restoring sanity", date:"22/05/2017", _children:[
       {date:"22/05/2017", title:"Restoring sanity 1", views: 12},
       {date:"11/02/2018", title:"Restoring sanity 2", views: 51},
       {date:"04/04/2018", title:"Restoring sanity 3", views: 103},
    ]},
    ]
    
    const topCalcViews = function (values, data, calcParams ) {
    let total = 0;
    values.forEach(function (value) {
        if (value > 0) {
            total += value;
            
        }
    });
    
    return total;
    }

const table = new Tabulator("#table", {
    height:400, 
    data:tabledata, 
    layout:"fitColumns", 
    dataTree: true,
    debugInvalidOptions: true,
    columns:[ 
        {title:"Title", field:"title" },
        {title:"Publish date", field:"date", hozAlign:"left", headerFilter:true},
        {title:"views", field:"views", topCalc: topCalcViews, formatter: function (cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
            let data = cell.getData();
            let totalViews = 0;

            if (data.isParent) {
                data._children.forEach(child => {
                        totalViews += child.views;
                });
                return totalViews;
            }
            else return cell.getValue();
        }
        }
    ],
});
```

As you can see in the fiddle, this works, except for the topCalc. To me this makes sense, as I am using a formatter and the data isn't really there? I guess that's why I can't make use of the built-in sum either.

What I want to happen: when I filter, I want the parent to recalculate the total views, so that the number of views is the same as all the rows that fall within the filter range. Now, the total-views stays the same.

I have tried a number of things to get this to work;

- I tried mutators instead of formatters, but there I run into some problems as well.
- I tried to use dataTreeChildColumnCalcs for topCalc, but then the total-views for the parent isn't updated either, obviously.
- I tried calling a reformat for the parent-rows to no avail

My purpose is to only display data, by the way. Currently, I have no plans for editing and I'll be using another table for exports. I think I can probably get away with both mutators as well as formatters.

I have been stuck for quite some time now. Any nudge into a promising direction is much appreciated!

**Answered!**
Thanks for the great answer, @Double H! For those interested, please note that you don't need to override the prototype if you want this to work. The topCalc and its formatted are sufficient!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See My Implementation. I hope you are looking something like this

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-70171937-po8bj?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Thank you! Definitely what I am looking for.

Now I only need to figure out how to extend the prototype. I am using this in a Chrome extension, not a module. Haven't done this yet. I will get back to you once I am sure your code is as solid as it seems. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you mind sharing what you did here? I went through your code and found out that I don't seem to need a lot of it.

What did you do with the prototype? If I remove that, it still seems to work fine. Also, why did you turn on the `dataTreeChildColumnCalcs`? That does not seem to be need either.

It's getting late, so I may be missing a test-case or two. I look forward to your answer!

Comment: Ye you are right, There is no need of overriding Prototype here see these fiddle `https://jsfiddle.net/ksuqb6pz`